# Execute get request for RunKeeper

Tags: android, http-get

I'm trying to make this request to the [RunKeeper API](http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/example-api-calls#example-get-retrieving-user-info):

> GET /user HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.runkeeper.com
>   Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   Accept: application/vnd.com.runkeeper.User+json

My code:

```
private static final String BASEURL = "http://api.runkeeper.com";  

public HttpResponse getUserInformation() throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF_8");
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);

    client.setParams(params);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(BASEURL.concat("/user"));
    String credentials = getCredentials();
    get.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
    get.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.com.runkeeper.User+json");
    return client.execute(get);
}

private String getCredentials() {
    String source = "Authorization" + ":" + "Bearer " + getAccessToken();
    String ret = Base64.encodeToString(source.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return ret;
}
```

But I keep getting:

> HTTP Status 500 - The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you're using is not correct. You're supposed to request `/user` only.

Add an accept header with this:

```
get.addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.com.runkeeper.User+json");
```

And are you sure you're adding your credentials information correctly? The documentation states that the Authorization header should look like `Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, while yours is `Basic ...`. Without looking into it further, perhaps this could be the solution:

```
get.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
```

If it still doesn't work properly, [this](http://developer.runkeeper.com/healthgraph/response-codes) page states that you should contact them to resolve the problem if you receive a Internal Server Error. I guess that could be done in [this Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/HealthGraph).

Comment: Okay, that seems to make sense, but I still get the same error. I've edited the question with the update.

Comment: I think the authentication works. Before, I kept getting the 401 error, http request need authentication. When I added this, I received the 500 error. When I remove the "Basic", I get the 401 error again.

I will try to contact RunKeeper as well.

Comment: Well, since you're getting a 500 error it might be due to the Authorization header being wrong. I suggest you try it, just to check.

Comment: ..And your last edit seemed to do the trick. I've copy pasted this code from another project which required authentication. Guess I should read better ;) Thanks!